# How to put an image beside the text of a ToolStripMenuItem (or similar control)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I know that it's possible to add an image to a `ToolStripMenuItem`, like in the "Close All Documents" item in the image below:

[image: Menu with some ToolStripMenuItems]

However, what I would like to achieve is something like this:

[image]

That is to place the image to the side of the item's text, but without overlapping the check space.
I have searched a bit but couldn't find a Winforms control that can do this.
Can you point me to any? Or do I have to implement my own?
Thank you.

EDIT: thanks everyone for the answers! I will accept one after the weekend.

Comment: I don't see any options. I may be wrong. But you could easily implement it. That shouldn't be that hard

Comment: maybe a custom renderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it from the designer, but you can show the extra margins by casting the parent DropDown property to a ToolStripDownDownMenu item to access the Show properties:

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)FileMenuItem.DropDown).ShowCheckMargin = true;
  ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)FileMenuItem.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = true;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I've accepted this answer because I can get a result close to what I wanted without writing much code.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use some custom painting. There are some ways to implement this, however I would like to introduce to using some custom `ToolStripRenderer`. The following is just a demo code, you can improve it yourself. I save each **inner Image** in the corresponding Item's `Tag` for convenience:

```
public class CustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    int innerImagePadding = 2;
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e) {
        Image img = e.Item.Tag as Image;
        if(img == null) base.OnRenderItemText(e);
        else {
          e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.Item.ContentRectangle.Left + e.Item.Bounds.Height + innerImagePadding,
                               e.Item.ContentRectangle.Top + innerImagePadding, 
                               Math.Max(1, e.Item.ContentRectangle.Height - innerImagePadding*2), 
                               Math.Max(1, e.Item.ContentRectangle.Height - innerImagePadding*2));              
          Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(e.Item.ContentRectangle.Left + e.Item.Bounds.Height*2, 
                               e.Item.ContentRectangle.Top +1, 
                               e.TextRectangle.Width, 
                               e.TextRectangle.Height);
          e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Text, e.TextFont, new SolidBrush(e.TextColor), textRect);
       }
    }
}

//Usage
ContextMenuStrip cm = new ContextMenuStrip();
cm.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Clear all", myImage) {Tag = myImage});
cm.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Remove all", myImage){Tag = myImage});
this.ContextMenuStrip = cm; //set the ContextMenuStrip for the form
//set the custom Renderer
cm.Renderer = new CustomRenderer();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can paint anything anywhere of the control with `paint` event. For example -

```
void myToolStripMenuItem1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("open_icon.jpg"), 0, 0);
}
```

This puts the image at (0,0) position. you can put it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a control in the standard .NET API that has this functionality, and therefore you have to write it yourself as a new feature.

However, depending on how often you want to use this "new" feature, there could be efficient ways of implementing it. One solution I believe could work neatly is to make use of the fact that these images have a fixed size, and indent the text accordingly.

Consider an approach such as the following:

```
using System.Drawing;

const string MENU_TEXT_INDENT = "           ";

private void MenuItemWithImage_Paint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    if (!menuItem.Text.StartsWith(MENU_TEXT_INDENT)) {
        menuItem.Text = menuItem.Text.Insert(0, MENU_TEXT_INDENT);
    }
    Image img = menuItem.Image;
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
    menuItem.Refresh(); // May be needed to reflect changes - try without though!
}
```

If you then attach this event handler to the `Paint` event of each menu item with an image to render in this way, this should work. (You may need more or less spaces - I haven't tested it myself)

Comment: this won't **align** text correctly unless we use some *fixed width* font.